# Sort one column of data in a csv file in ascending order in java

Tags: java, sorting, csv

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data1.csv"));        
Map<String, String> map=new TreeMap<String, String>();
String line="";
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){                
        map.put(getField(line),line);
        }
        reader.close();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("sorted_numbers.txt");
for(String val : map.values()){
    writer.write(val);      
    writer.write('\n');        
        }
        writer.close();
}
private static String getField(String line) {
    return line.split(",")[0];//extract value you want to sort on    
}
}
```

Hia
I am trying to read a unsorted file and get Java to sort one column of the csv data file and print those results in a new file. I borrowed this solution whilst I was searching on this website because I think it is ideal for what I am trying to acomplish.  I have a 282 rows of data in the form of

```
UserID, Module, Mark

Ab004ui, g46PRo, 54

cb004ui, g46GRo, 94

gy004ui, g46GRo, 12

ab004ui, g46PRo, 34
```

this is in the csv file. 
when I use the above code it only gives me one line in the sorted_marks.txt, like this

```
ab004ui, g46PRo, 34
```

and I believe it wasnt even sorted.

I want all the results from the new file to be sorted based on their userID and nothing else but I can't seem to get it to work, please any help would be greatful

Comment: Be careful, that if you use a Map, if you have duplicate keys, they will be overwritten and you will lose them.

Comment: instead of using Map, what yould you suggest using? I have just noticed that not all of the data is there now, as many of userID are the same and so have been overwritten. What an idiot :(. Damn. how would I rectify this?

Comment: I made it like this: (maybe it's not the best solution) I still used a map, BUT when I put objects in it, I check if the key already exists (calling `containsKey(key)`)  if it is already in there, I call `containsKey(key+"_001")`, `containsKey(key+"_002")` ... in a while block. When I don't find such a  key, I call  `put(key+"_003", value)`. Instead of "_" you can use space or a character that you know it won't be in any user id. This method may not be optimal, especially when you have lots of data, but at least it works.

Comment: Another solution is to use `Multimap` of Google Collections

Comment: I just tried this bc I was thinking along the same lines but for some reason when I implement with my data1.csv file it makes no difference, I think it is because of userID numbering and lettering. Is possible for me to send you the data file, so you can see what I mean?

Comment: Ive never used it multimap before, is it difficult to implement? I think I may just overcomplicated this problem slightly. I can sort normal arrays, no problem but reading the data file and sorting then creating a new file has really messed me up.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. In my user page you find my website. There, go to the Contact page, you'll find an e-mail.

Comment: Using `Multimap` is easy: first download the jar from http://code.google.com/p/google-collections . When you put in a `Multimap` objects with the same key, it will actually save a list of objects for that key. Then you use `asMap()` method which will return a `Map<String, Collection<String>`.

Comment: Thank you, I will get some reading around the subject. I have sent you the email regarding the data file. It does seem simple enough, to many hours spent looking at the screen has made me forget things lol, thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the new lines from data1.csv.

I would prefer to use the second generic String of the Map as a list of string and everything is almost same like below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data1.csv"));
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
        String line = reader.readLine();//read header
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String key = getField(line);
            List<String> l = map.get(key);
            if (l == null) {
                l = new LinkedList<String>();
                map.put(key, l);
            }
            l.add(line);

        }
        reader.close();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("sorted_numbers.txt");
        writer.write("UserID, Module, Mark\n");
        for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
            for (String val : list) {
                writer.write(val);
                writer.write("\n");
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    private static String getField(String line) {
        return line.split(",")[0];// extract value you want to sort on
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for this, I have marked this as the answer, I am acutally going to get some reading done on maps, as this is a very interesting way of completing this problem. Now all I have to do is make it into a method and im done. Thanks again for all your help and explanations

Answer (score 0):

You probably want line.split(",")[0], not space.  But you should also trim the white space from beginning and end of your sort key using the appropriate string function.

Comment: yey that works but for some reason it has made it a big block of results, like this: Ab004ui, g46PRo, 54, cb004ui, g46GRo, 94. rather then each result on indiviudal lines. so it should return it like:

ab004ui, g46PRo, 34
cd004ui, G46PRo, 29

Comment: You might want to repost your code.  The code that's posted does seem to be writing a newline at the end of each row.  Check that that's still there.

Comment: I edited my original post and added what you suggested, the comma. but not trim() string function, as I keep on getting error. I think I am not adding it right to the code. Also Map is overwriting the userID of the same type which is annoying, is anyway of stopping it from doing that?