# Sorting tab delimited file based on column in java

Tags: java, sorting, csv

I have huge (approximately 4GB) text file that needed to be sorted. It is so huge that it has 6 thousand coumns and thousands of rows. It is very easy to sort with bash script. However, i am in need of cross platform java program to sort the file. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894060/sort-one-column-of-data-in-a-csv-file-in-ascending-order-in-java), but i got the same result file as sorted output file.

**Part of input file to be sorted**

```
SNP_ID  Sub_0001    Sub_0002    Sub_0003    Sub_0004 ...
cnv3p502    0   0   0   0
rs3115860   1   0   1   1        
rs3131967   1   0   1   1        
rs3115850   1   0   1   1
rs12124819  0   0   0   0
rs2519031   1   0   1   1   
.
.
.
```

I need to sort this tab delimited file with respect to first column in java without using system commands that executes unix commands. I will be appreciating your help.

Comment: why dont you do an external sort? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Answer (score 0):

Like Dhruv's comment said, one of the possible approaches is to use external sort.

What you'd want to do is create an object that encapsulates each line of your file and create a custom comparator that sorts by the criteria you need. Keep in mind that you don't need to map every column on the line to an Object property, you can simply have a property containing the first column of each row to use as the comparison property, and another property containing the whole String.

Load a chunk of the file, line by line, into a Collection of said Object type. Sort it using your custom comparator. Write the collection to a temporary file. Repeat until the end of the original file.

You'll end up with several smaller files, sorted by themselves. Now you use the "merge" step of external sort to create a new file containing all the rows sorted. Read the first line of each file, write the smallest of them to the sorted file, read a new line from the file that had the smallest one. Repeat until all temporary files are empty.

Done.