# How to sort a csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I want to create a file in this format:

```
device1,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5
device2,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5
device3,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10
device4,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10
```

Here, `t1, t2, ..., tn` are time stamps.

Every value `tn` is generated based on one execution of JAR file along with that device name gets generated too.

I am able to generate a format like this using the JAR file now:

For example:

**Current format in csv file:**

```
device1,t1,device2,t2,device2,t3,device1,t4,device2,t5,device2,t6,device1,t7,device2,t8
```

**I want this in this format in csv file:**

**device1**-t1,t4,t7
**device2**-t2,t3,t5,t6,t8

So here, I have to put the time stamp belonging to specific devices on the right-hand side.

Please let me know how can I sort it in Java.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you show us say a few lines of actual data, along with the output you are expecting?

Comment: Also, show what you have done so far.

Comment: One could read the data from the csv file into the Java program and organize it into a data structure like Map<Device, List<Timestamp>>, then flush it back into a csv file.

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894328/3157062) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this question here as per my understanding of your question.
What you can do is to create a hashmap which stores device name as hashmap key.
And then for values create a sortedCollection.

Feed your timestamp in this sorted collection and keep updating this HashMap for the corresponding device name key.

As and when you will update your sorted timestamp collections, they will automatically be stored in sorted manner.

your hashmap will look like :

key     :     value (collection)

device1 :    t1, t4, t7

device2  :   t2, t5, t8 (add more timestamp in the end of this collection)

Then feed this hashmap data in the CSV file.

This is to do from java end.

If you want to sort in csv whenever a new timestamp is added for a device, then I dont think so that you can do this from java. Then you would have to keep some logic in csv file once all your data is added in csv file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution,. I am able to do the same on csv file:

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

I got output as:
Entire map:{Device1=[[t8], t9], Device2=[[[[[t2], t3], t5], t7], t10]}

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("results.csv"));

                String eachline;
               // int i=2, j=2;
                while((eachline = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] fields = eachline.split(",");

                    if(Integer.parseInt(fields[2])==0)//data is = 0
                    {
                        if(tree.get(fields[0])!=null)//returns null if this key not present
                        {
                        values.add(tree.get(fields[0]));//get entire key value pair for that particular field
                        }
                        values.add(fields[1]);//to prev value, add next value
                        tree.put(fields[0], values.toString());// write to hashmap along with value
                        values.clear();
                    }
                }


                System.out.println("Entire map:"+tree);
```